# Xml query with cross join on large dataset. how to increase performance

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xpath

I have the following query which takes about 50 seconds for 100 records, however using a count i have determined that the results set will be 100 000 items 
(this is for a report) so i am looking for ways to increase performance.

```
SELECT TOP 200
OL.*,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="storename"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)') AS storename,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="pwnumber"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)') AS pwnumber,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="department"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)') AS department,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="item"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)') AS item,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="barcode"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS barcode,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="oldprice"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS oldprice,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="newprice"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS newprice,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="goodsgroup"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS goodsgroup,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="startdate"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS startdate,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="prodgroup"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS prodgroup,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="season"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS season,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="pkquantity"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS pkquantity,
LI.LineItem.value('Field[@name="recordtype"][1]/@value', 'varchar(MAX)')AS recordtype
FROM [lines] OL
LEFT JOIN [Clineextension] OLE ON OL.OrderLineId = OLE.OrderLineId
CROSS APPLY OLE.LineItems.nodes('/LineItems/LineItem') as LI(LineItem)
WHERE Customer = 1302
AND StatusId > 1
```

i think that especially the select statements can be improved but i am not sure how.

any ideas?
any help is greatly appreciated.

other info
sql server 2005
all rights
xml field vary per customer

Comment: Do the XML columns have [XML indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097(v=SQL.100).aspx) on them? If they don't take a look at the MSDN article [XML Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121(v=SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Indexing on XML Columns and the performance will increase drastically.

Comment: this was indeed a huge performance gain (on the qa system), however we decided to simple use an aplication to load the full xml and then build a report in the application because this was verry easy to implement on our existing framework and cost less time than building an xml index over a over a multi million records table with a lot of xml per